# How to match specific characters only?

Tags: python, regex

Here I am try to match the specific characters in a string,

```
^[23]*$
```

Here my cases,

1. `2233` --> **Match**
2. `22` --> Not Match
3. `33` --> Not Match
4. `2435` --> Not Match
5. `2322` --> **Match**
6. `323` --> **Match**

I want to match the string with correct regular expression. I mean 1,5,6 cases needed.

Update:

If I have more than two digits match, like the patterns,

`234` or `43` or etc. how to match this pattern with any string ?.

I want dynamic matching ?

Comment: What is the condition that you search for? That there's a place where 2 is followed by a 3 *or* that it exists both at least a 2 and 3 in the string?

Comment: I want both 2 and 3 in the string and without any other digits. In my case order is not important, But must 2 and 3 need to match in given string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
(2+3|3+2)[23]*$
```

String must either:

- start with one or more 2s, contain a 3, followed by any mix of 2 or 3 only
- start with one or more 3s, contain a 2, followed by any mix of 2 or 3 only

**Update: to parameterize the pattern**

To parameterize this pattern, you could do something like:

```
x = 2
y = 3
pat = re.compile("(%s+%s|%s+%s)[%s%s]*$" % (x,y,y,x,x,y))
pat.match('2233')
```

Or a bit clearer, but longer:

```
pat = re.compile("({x}+{y}|{y}+{x})[{x}{y}]*$".format(x=2, y=3))
```

Or you could use Python [template strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)

**Update: to handle more than two characters:**

If you have more than two characters to test, then the regex gets unwieldy and my other answer becomes easier:

```
def match(s,ch):
    return all([c in s for c in ch]) and len(s.translate(None,ch)) == 0

match('223344','234') # True
match('2233445, '234') # False
```

**Another update: use sets**

I wasn't entirely happy with the above solution, as it seemed a bit ad-hoc. Eventually I realized it's just a set comparison - we just want to check that the input consists of a fixed set of characters:

```
def match(s,ch):
    return set(s) == set(ch)
```

Comment: I think this will work (but I think mine will work too!) Your answer looks a bit simpler to me though, so is better.

Comment: I need only string must contain 2 and 3 without any other digits. like `323` or `2233` or etc. But I don't need to match `22344`. here you are failed in this case http://rubular.com/r/iEdVTFOboD

Comment: Now fixed - need to check for end of line `$` in each of the alternatives, rather than at the end.

Comment: `^(2+3|3+2)[23]*$` same but shorter?

Comment: Yes, I think so, nice refactoring! Will edit...also noticed that the leading `^` isn't needed

Comment: Without the leading `^` strings like `abc44333222` would match. From what I understood all of it should be 2's and 3's.

Comment: @ralvik works using `pat.match()` e.g. `pat.match('abc2233')` is `None`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :) Not very well versed in python.

Comment: @DNA great answer, Sorry for asking this, But If I have three or four or one digits etc..like `x = '2' , y= '3', z = '4'`. Then your expression is so long. I am not challenging you, Because my English is so poor. I am expecting positive reply. Thanks again..:)

Comment: Answer updated to handle this, using my other (non-regex) solution.

Comment: Thanks for your great effort. I am happy with your answer...:)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match strings containing both 2 and 3, but no other characters you could use lookaheads combined with what you already have:

`^(?=.*2)(?=.*3)[23]*$`

The lookaheads `(?=.*2)` and `(?=.*3)` assert the presence of 2 and 3, and `^[23]*$` matches the actual string to only those two characters.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a solution using regex (which I have posted), but here's an alternative approach:

```
def match(s):
  return '2' in s and '3' in s and len(s.translate(None,'23')) == 0
```

We check that the string contains both desired characters, then translate them both to empty strings, then check that there's nothing left (i.e. we *only* had 2s and 3s).

This approach can easily be extended to handle more than two characters, using the `all` function, and a list comprehension:

```
def match(s,ch):
    return all([c in s for c in ch]) and len(s.translate(None,ch)) == 0
```

which would be used as follows:

```
match('223344','234') # True
match('2233445, '234') # False
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't agree with your answer. unfortunately both are wrong

Comment: Oops, yes - hopefully now fixed.

Comment: Thanks but which is the best way ?

Comment: The regex is clearly shorter, and probably faster (if that matters - and you'd need to measure it!) but slightly harder to understand. I'd use the regex, but add an explanatory comment.

Comment: Thanks one last question can I pass the chars to regex like `x='2', y='3' and expression = (x+y|y+x)[xy]*$`

Comment: I have updated my other answer with a couple of ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (both 2 and 3 should exist)

```
^([2]+[3]+[23]*)|([3]+[2]+[23]*)$
```

Comment: sorry It also match's the `2342`. I need only `2332` or `323` etc..order is not important.http://rubular.com/r/wtnDaMp9AN

Comment: it can not match 2342, it can match only 2 and 3  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(2[23]*3[23]*)|(3[23]*2[23]*)$
```

I think this will do it. Look for either a 2 at the start, then a 3 has to appear somewhere (surrounded by as many other 2s and 3s as needed). Or vice versa, with 3 at the start and a 2 somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Should start with 2 or 3 followed by 2 or more occurrence of 2 or 3

```
    ^[23][23]{2,}$
```

Comment: This is more or less the same as the poster's original regex, except you require a minimum length of 3 instead of 0. As with the poster's you do not assert that both 2 and 3 is present. So strings like `22222` will match.